# celery group runs tasks sequentially instead of in parallel

Tags: python, celery

I am learning celery group function

```
@celery_app.task
def celery_task():
    import time
    time.sleep(30)
    print('task 1')

@celery_app.task
def celery_task2():
    import time
    time.sleep(10)
    print('task 2')

@celery_app.task
def test():
    from datetime import datetime
    print(datetime.now())
    job = group(
        celery_task.s(),
        celery_task2.s()
    )
    result = job()
    result.get()
    print(datetime.now())
```

However, as i was running `test()` from the python console and viewing them in the celery logs, it seems that task1 was run then task2 was run.

Shouldnt it be run in parallel? The whole `test()` function took 30s to complete

To start up my celery workers i use the command `celery -A tasks worker -l=INFO`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that the whole `test()` took 30s? If so, I don't understand what's the problem? If it wasn't parallel - it had to take 30s+10s=40s.

Two things here:

1. Use `--concurrency` flag when you run your worker so it can handle more than one task. Alternatively, use more than one worker (run two processes):
   `celery -A tasks worker -l=INFO --concurrency=4` (I'm not sure what is the default - I guess that's one).
2. Run your canvas asynchronously with `job.delay()` or `job. apply_async()` to run async.

Comment: Oh yes thanks. I didn’t realize I set the code to sleep for 30s instead of 20s